# Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed on React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, webview, crash, bag

#### Good day! Every week my app crashes in the production mode on android devices. Basically it is happening on Xiaomi, Samsung, LGE phones with Android 10.

***Bug description:***
The app crashes in the production mode with an exception: Caused by android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException
Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed

```
Caused by android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewContextAndSetProvider(WebViewFactory.java:339)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:402)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:252)
       at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:47)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.getCookieManager(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:180)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.get(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:58)
       at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest(JavaNetCookieJar.java:61)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer.loadForRequest(ReactCookieJarContainer.java:44)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:84)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

***Expected behavior:***
The app is not crashes.

***Environment:***

- OS: Android
- OS version: Android 10
- react-native version: 0.62.0
- react-native-webview version: 9.2.2

Comment: Facing the same issue, it seems still there is no solution
1. https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/14
2. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32653